# Slow jQuery / Highcharts Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart with 144 different series, all with 30 points. They are all selectable and shown in the legend. They're all initially set to "visible: false" so that the user can make their selection.

They are all variations of 8 default lines with 3 different "categories" that you can select. These categories have 3, 3, and 2 options respectively, giving you 144 possible curves (8*3*3*2 = 144).

I created dropdowns which allow a user to filter based on these categories. This worked, but was extremely slow, and often crashed the browser. To optimize it, I made it so that Highcharts won't render the lines until the user selects all 3 of the options. This improved performance, but it's still lackluster.

Since then, I've added the Highcharts boost module, as well as disabling "enableMouseTracking". This helped, but it's still slow. The lines load instantly when the user selects them from the legend, but they are very slow when you make the selection from the dropdown. This makes me think that the problem lies with the drop down filters I created. Below is the code (the 3 categories are condition, cost, percentile):

```
function(chart) {
  $('.condition').change(function() {
    condition = this.value;

    if (condition) {
    Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(ob, j) {  
      if ((ob.userOptions.condition == condition && 
        ob.userOptions.percentile == percentile) && 
       (ob.userOptions.cost == cost) {
        ob.show()
      } else {
        ob.hide()
      }
    });
  }
});


$('.cost').change(function() {
  cost = this.value;
  if (cost) {
    Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(ob, j) {

      if ((ob.userOptions.cost == cost && 
      ob.userOptions.percentile == percentile) && 
      (ob.userOptions.condition == condition)) {
        ob.show()
      } else {
        ob.hide()
      }
    });
  }
});

$('.percentile').change(function() {
  percentile = this.value;
  if (percentile) {
      Highcharts.each(chart.series, function(ob, j) {
      if ((ob.userOptions.percentile == percentile && 
      ob.userOptions.condition == condition) &&
      (ob.userOptions.cost == cost)) {
        ob.show()
      } else {
        ob.hide()
      }
    });
  }
 }) 
});
```

Comment: So, you're showing/hiding a large number of series, one at a time, each time a filter is changed?  This is always going to be slow. I would do this differently - hold the series objects in external arrays, and when the filter is updated, either remove existing series and add the new (delaying the chart redraw until the end, or destroy the chart and build it again.

Comment: Using hide and show is redrawing your chart every time you are using them, that is the reason why you have your problem. Why not to use setVisible with redraw set to false instead? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setVisible
You can make redraw after you will set visibility of all your series.

Comment: Solution was to change ob.show to ob.setVisible(true,true) and ob.hide() to ob.setVisible(false,false). The plots appear instantly now - thank you G.B.